# Can i build some projects in one repository by Travis?

Tags: java, maven, github, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I have GitHub repository where i located 3 different maven projects. My question is: can i somehow set up Travis on separately building these projects. If i can then how? I would be even acceptable to rebuild all projects after changing only one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `.travis.yml` script in you repo, just change `first/second/third` on path to your poms.

```
language: java

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      jdk: oraclejdk8

script:
  - mvn -q -B -f first/pom.xml clean verify
  - mvn -q -B -f second/pom.xml clean verify
  - mvn -q -B -f third/pom.xml clean verify
```